# MySQL installed but no mysql command found

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum, mysql

I'm trying to install MySQL 5.1.69 server community onto a RHEL 6 system (although it's outdated; I want to replicate an issue reported on this version).

I installed a MySQL 5.1 PRM, downloaded from MySQL archives folder:

```
# which mysql
/usr/bin/which: no mysql in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/myusername/bin)

# mysql -u root -p
-bash: mysql: command not found

# ls /usr/bin/my*
/usr/bin/myisamchk                   /usr/bin/mysql_fix_extensions
/usr/bin/myisam_ftdump               /usr/bin/mysql_fix_privilege_tables
/usr/bin/myisamlog                   /usr/bin/mysqlhotcopy
/usr/bin/myisampack                  /usr/bin/mysql_install_db
/usr/bin/my_print_defaults           /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
/usr/bin/mysqlbug                    /usr/bin/mysql_setpermission
/usr/bin/mysql_config                /usr/bin/mysqltest
/usr/bin/mysql_convert_table_format  /usr/bin/mysql_tzinfo_to_sql
/usr/bin/mysqld_multi                /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe                 /usr/bin/mysql_zap
```

Why is there no `mysql` program?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are 2 metapackages: `mysql-server` and `mysql-client`.
Looks like you have only the server pakage installed.

That is at least how it works in Debian.

Try installing `mysql-client`

Comment: that's weird I have virtual machine here installed `mysql-server` with no having issue with `-bash: mysql: command not found`

Comment: @EAL Then this VM supposedly has both `mysql-server` and `mysql-client` installed. That was easy.